# Updating to active class in navigation bar using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to manipulate my css so that any of the navigation bar links are clicked it is updated to active class and the clicked bar changes its attributes according to the css stylesheet. But, there are no changes in my navbar when I click on Home, or contact, etc. It doesn't work.

Here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    console.log(location.pathname.split('/')[1]);
    $('nav a[href^="'+location.pathname.split('/')[1]+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

CSS code:

```
nav a {
    display: block;  
    width:100%;  
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background-color:firebrick;
}

nav a.active {
    background:blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: antiquewhite;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="JQuery.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="copy.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="JQuery.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="JQuery.html">Contact Pranshu</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Don't paste images of your code, Post the actual code.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Btw your code works just fine when you run it, So add your html and jquery code please

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] (pictures of code do not count)

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work this way ... you are setting this class on the current page ... and then the browser goes load a _different_ page, _because_ you just clicked on a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding code on [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event you have to add your code on `$(document).ready(function(){});` . Because the codes inside you click event execute only after the click of the selector and code inside [`ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) execute when the DOM is fully loaded. Here in your scenario you need to execute the code after page load not after click. So your code looks like as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log(location.pathname.split('/')[1]); 
    $('nav a[href^="'+location.pathname.split('/') [1]+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Testing addClass on click event.

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var href = $(this).attr('href');
console.log(href)
$('a').removeClass('active');
$('nav a[href^="'+href+'"]').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
nav a{
   display: block;  
   width:100%;  
   padding: 20px 20px;
   background-color:firebrick;

}
nav a.active{
background:blue;
text-decoration: none;
color:antiquewhite;
}
nav li{
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="JQuery.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="copy.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="JQuery.html">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="JQuery.html">Contact Pranshu</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: thats what I initially had in the code, but it didn't work so I changed it to click to see if it would work...

Comment: @Tanshiv2 what are you getting on `location.pathname.split('/')[1]`